# Use generate statement to create 'n' array of registers in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl, intel-fpga, flip-flop

I am converting an old AHDL code to VHDL, and I need to create 5 arrays of resisters using a `generate` statement. I've never used `generate` before, and after trying for a couple of hours I still can't find an answer for my problem. My initial approach was to use a 18 bit input array, and a 18 bit output array, but I know that that's not the way to do it.

This is the code I have right now:

```
entity setup_comp_reg is

    generic(
    NUM_ID: integer := 18
   );

  port ( 
  clk:      in std_logic;  
  D:            in std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);   
  clrn:     in std_logic;   
  ena:      in std_logic;   

  Q:            out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0)

  );
end setup_comp_reg;

architecture rtl of setup_comp_reg is

begin

DFFE: process (clk, clrn, ena) -- 18 times, using generate 
begin

    if (clrn = '0') then
        Q<= (others => '0');

    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then

        if (ena = '1') then
            Q<= D;
        end if;

    end if;
end process;


end rtl;
```

So, I already have the DFFE, but how to use generate to create 5 arrays with 18 bits each?

The AHDL code is pretty self explanatory, it might help too:

```
for i in 17 to 0 generate                       
            rg_bit_time[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)      = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adBT&iWR);
            rg_sample_time[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)   = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adSP&iWR);
            rg_low_sync[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)      = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adLS&iWR);
            rg_hi_sync[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)       = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adHS&iWR);
    end generate;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You already have generated 18 DFFEs, without Generate, because D and Q are 18 bits wide. So what are you really asking? If you want 18 registers each with 18 bits, you first have to decide how you want to interconnect them.

Comment: I need to create the DFFEs without 18 bits input and outputs. The old AHDL code was pretty straight forward, I need to do the same as this (below) because I'll have 5 arrays of 18 bit resgisters. Here's the AHDL: 
 for i in 17 to 0 generate                                                                                          
 rg_bit_time[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena) = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset,  enable[i]);         
       end generate;

Comment: So you want 18 one bit registers. You still need to define how they are interconnected. If you just need 18 individual inputs and 18 individual output your code above is fine, just pick bits off the `std_logic_vector` in the  module above this one. `std_logic_vector` is just an abstraction over individual bits; that's what you get in a higher level language.

Comment: So, there is no need to use generate? I'll just need to copy and paste the code of the DFFE  to create the 5 new arrays?

Comment: What 5 arrays?  Oh you edited the comment. This is like jelly. I can't read your mind, please update the question with what you want to do and the AHDL equivalent. If you need 5 instances of setup_comp_reg, it doesn't matter if you instantiate it 5 times individually or in one for..generate statement.

Comment: The question is updated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see the design intent in the ahdl code, there seems to be no port mapping for Q, and I have no idea of the significance of & in the middle of a name. I'll have to leave this for someone who still remembers AHDL.

Comment: The AHDL generate statement represents four flip flops for each iteration of i. Your entity is missing port signal declarations for iDATA (presumed to be D), reg_reset (presumed to be clr_n without the not), adBT, adSP, adLS, adHS and iWR (note only VHDL -2008 will allow non-static expressions as actuals, where sup ported by your tool implementation e.g. adLS and iWR). It's not clear which of the 4 Q is meant to be (rg_bit_time, rg_sample_time, rg_low_sync or rg_hi_sync) but you don't have enough outputs either. ena isn't needed in the DFFE process sensitivity list.

Comment: Your confusion appears to stem from the AHDL priimitive for DFFE which is described with a function prototype: FUNCTION DFFE (d, clk, clrn, prn, ena) RETURNS (q) ;. The only place to  hang the name for it's q output is in the assignment (which associates what would be formals with actuals in VHDL). See the [Altera Hardware Description Language (AHDL) Language Reference Manual](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/Altera_Hardware_Description_Language_(AHDL)_Language_Reference_Manual). The names would be associated with q outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AHDL generate statement represents four flip flops for each iteration of i.

AHDL generate statement:

```
for i in 17 to 0 generate                       
            rg_bit_time[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)      = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adBT&iWR);
            rg_sample_time[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)   = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adSP&iWR);
            rg_low_sync[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)      = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adLS&iWR);
            rg_hi_sync[i].(d, clk, clrn, ena)       = (iDATA[i], clk, not reg_reset, adHS&iWR);
    end generate;
```

AHDL uses a function prototype to represent primitives (here, DFFE). The return value would be the q output (and isn't mentioned in the AHDL generate statement). There are four assignments to names with function prototype associations. That represents four arrays of 18 flip flops.

The function prototype for the DFFE register is shown in the [Altera Hardware Description Language (AHDL) Language Reference Manual](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/Altera_Hardware_Description_Language_(AHDL)_Language_Reference_Manual), Section 3, Primitives, Flip Flop and latch Primitives, Table 3-9. MAX+PLUS II Flipflops & Latches:

[image: Table 3.9]

Where the return value would be associated with the name (e.g. rg_bit_time[i]) in assignment statements in the AHDL generate statement.

In VHDL we'd do that by associating actuals with formals of a DFFE entity that would include the output.

A behavioral representation with ports for all the outputs and inputs would look something like:

```
library ieee;                   -- ADDED context clause
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity setup_comp_reg is

    generic (
        NUM_ID: integer := 18
    );

    port ( 
        clk:            in  std_logic;  
        D:              in  std_logic_vector(NUM_ID - 1 downto 0);   
        clrn:           in  std_logic;   
        ena:            in  std_logic;   
        -- Q:        out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0)
        WR:             in  std_logic;  -- ADDED
        adBT:           in  std_logic;  -- ADDED
        adSP:           in  std_logic;  -- ADDED
        adLS:           in  std_logic;  -- ADDED
        adHS:           in  std_logic;  -- ADDED
        rg_bit_time:    out std_logic_vector(NUM_ID - 1 downto 0); -- ADDED
        rg_sample_time: out std_logic_vector(NUM_ID - 1 downto 0); -- ADDED
        rg_low_sync:    out std_logic_vector(NUM_ID - 1 downto 0); -- ADDED
        rg_hi_sync:     out std_logic_vector(NUM_ID - 1 downto 0)  -- ADDED
    );
end entity setup_comp_reg;

architecture rtl of setup_comp_reg is
    -- For no -2008 dependency, ADD these:
    signal adBTWR:      std_logic;
    signal adSPWR:      std_logic;
    signal adLSWR:      std_logic;
    signal adHSWR:      std_logic;
begin
-- Write ENABLE conditions:

    adBTWR <= adBT and WR;
    adSPWR <= adSP and WR;
    adLSWR <= adLS and WR;
    adHSWR <= adHS and WR;

SETUP_REGS:
    for i in NUM_ID - 1 downto 0 generate
BIT_TIME:
        process (clk, clrn)  -- enables not needed in sensitivity list
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_bit_time(i)  <= '0';
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adBTWR = '1' then
                    rg_bit_time(i) <= D(i);
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
SAMPLE_TIME:
        process (clk, clrn)
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_sample_time(i)  <= '0';
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adSPWR = '1' then
                    rg_sample_time(i) <= D(i);
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
LOW_SYNC:
        process (clk, clrn)
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_low_sync(i)  <= '0';
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adLSWR = '1' then
                    rg_low_sync(i) <= D(i);
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
HI_SYNC:
        process (clk, clrn)
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_hi_sync(i)  <= '0';
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adHSWR = '1' then
                    rg_hi_sync(i) <= D(i);
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    end generate;

end architecture rtl;
```

You could associate individual flip flops from an entity (DFFE) but there's no need in a VHDL Register Transfer Logic (RTL) representation.  In AHDL you'd have no choice, a named element would be a flip flop associated more than likely with a pin of a device.

You could also streamline the above description, it's written this way to show providence with the AHDL generate statement (without individual flip flops).

Using a generate statement with instantiated flip flops would elaborate to  i number of nested block statements for the instantiation, the outer for the port map, the inner containing one or more processes implementing the flip flop for each of the four names. The above does that without instantiation (saving one block statement nesting level).

A description using loop statements instead of the generate statement would eliminate all the processes for individual flip flops and could be collapsed further by using assignment with a target that's an array object:

```
architecture rtl1 of setup_comp_reg is
    -- For no -2008 dependency, ADD these:
    signal adBTWR:      std_logic;
    signal adSPWR:      std_logic;
    signal adLSWR:      std_logic;
    signal adHSWR:      std_logic;
begin
-- Write ENABLE conditions:

    adBTWR <= adBT and WR;
    adSPWR <= adSP and WR;
    adLSWR <= adLS and WR;
    adHSWR <= adHS and WR;

-- SETUP_REGS:
BIT_TIME:
        process (clk, clrn)  -- enables not needed in sensitivity list
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_bit_time  <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adBTWR = '1' then
                    rg_bit_time <= D;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
SAMPLE_TIME:
        process (clk, clrn)
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_sample_time  <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adSPWR = '1' then
                    rg_sample_time <= D;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
LOW_SYNC:
        process (clk, clrn)
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_low_sync  <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adLSWR = '1' then
                    rg_low_sync <= D;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
HI_SYNC:
        process (clk, clrn)
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_hi_sync  <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adHSWR = '1' then
                    rg_hi_sync <= D;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
end architecture rtl1;
```

That's four process statements.

The canny ready will notice the code could be compacted further by using separate enables for the named register outputs:

```
architecture rtl2 of setup_comp_reg is
    signal adBTWR:      std_logic;
    signal adSPWR:      std_logic;
    signal adLSWR:      std_logic;
    signal adHSWR:      std_logic;
begin
-- Write ENABLE conditions:
    adBTWR <= adBT and WR;
    adSPWR <= adSP and WR;
    adLSWR <= adLS and WR;
    adHSWR <= adHS and WR;

BT_SP_LS_HS:
        process (clk, clrn)  -- enables not needed in sensitivity list
        begin
            if clrn = '0' then
                rg_bit_time  <= (others => '0');
                rg_sample_time  <= (others => '0');
                rg_low_sync  <= (others => '0');
                rg_hi_sync  <= (others => '0');
            elsif rising_edge (clk) then
                if adBTWR = '1' then
                    rg_bit_time <= D;
                end if;
                if adSPWR = '1' then
                    rg_sample_time <= D;
                end if;
                if adLSWR = '1' then
                    rg_low_sync <= D;
                end if;
                if adHSWR = '1' then
                    rg_hi_sync <= D;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
end architecture rtl2;
```

Process statements are the unit of simulation in VHDL. The fewer there are the less execution overhead from suspension and resumption. The rtl2 example has one process statement. It works without having all the enables in the sensitivity list because they are 'sampled' on the clock rising edge. The authority for leaving the enables out comes from IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (now withdrawn, RTL Synthesis) which describes syntax for and the required sensitivity list elements for edge sensitive sequential logic. Vendors typically provide examples of a subset of the sequential logic forms they will support and are guaranteed to comply with 1076.6.

The VHDL code above all analyzes.

(Looks like part of an IC tester.)

Comment: Ok, this answers my question. Just one more thing, using the generate statement is not as good as using **rtl2** architecture? I should go for the **rtl2**, right? Thank You for our help.

Comment: Actel's generate statement supports bottom up design (with register primitives) that's not needed in VHDL which supports implied registers through RTL synthesis. The lack of RTL synthesis is a limitation in AHDL. All three architectures would generate equivalent net lists. The last, rtl2 would be better for simulation when porting more of a system design into the same higher density modern device or performing system simulation.